# Cancel button in Navigation View not working

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

[image: Cancel Button]
code for cancel button is

```
- (IBAction)cancelButton:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

While tracing the program I can see the method is  called however the view is not dissmissing to the previous view controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use Navigation View controller you should use

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

instead of dismissViewControllerAnimated

PS actually, I think you use storyboards and segues and in this case you should use UnwindSegue [What are Unwind segues for and how do you use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them)
Also you should read some common documentation about in app navigation...

Comment: no popViewControllerAnimated found. When I use the full syntax I get `No visible @interface for 'AddConatctViewController' declares the selector 'popViewControllerAnimated:'`

Comment: sorry, i've missed the navigationController. Check the fixed code

Comment: not the AddConatctViewController  pop viewController, it's navigationController pop viewController